# How to resolve client.guilds.cache.get().commands cannot read properties of undefined?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Before discordjs update my code works well but now with the update this part doesn't work.

```
module.exports = {
  name : 'ready',
  once : true,
  async execute(client){
    const devGuild = await client.guilds.cache.get('243406719638568960')
    devGuild.commands.set(client.commands.map(cmd => cmd))
  }
}
```

**devGuild** is undefined. How can I resolve the error to set my commands:

> UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commands'), Origine : uncaughtException

Comment: Try fetching the guild

Comment: @Elitezen fetch the guild ?

Comment: If the `cache.get` didn't work try to fetch it

Comment: What @Elitezen means is that instead of using `client.guilds.cache.get()`, you can use `await client.guilds.fetch()`